# Margin guide not appear when drag component on interface builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

When I drag any component, the margin guide does not appear like in this image:

[image: Drag&Drop lines]

Are there any settings where I can enable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select Editor > Snap to Guides.